# How to install Miktex on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, latex

I am having Lubuntu 18.04 and want to install miktex, but when I install it shows unmet dependencies because I think it is for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Is there any way I can install it on Lubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 has the same dependency rules as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't know `miktex` and cannot find it in the repositories (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=miktex) so more details (such as link to where it's from for those of us that aren't familiar with it), and/or the messages you see on installing it may allow us to provide more direct help.

Comment: Thanks @dlin, installed texlive and it is working!